# When can you take a [Bonus attack]?

Tags: legend

Is the intended interpretation that you can get your [Bonus attack] out of an attack action? Possibly even out of my turn, since nothing seems to prevent that?

I just started delving into [Legend](http://www.ruleofcool.com/), and since I'm coming from the D20 system (and knowing that Legend has is root in it), the lack of indication of when to perform my [Bonus attack] seams strange to me ([V1.1](http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,1341.0.html), p. 215):

> **[Bonus attack]** denotes an attack you may make at a given time. You may only benefit from one [Bonus attack] per [Round]. A [Bonus attack] is made at your full Base Attack Bonus unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 5):

By default, you cannot use a [Bonus Attack], which is why there is no action associated with it. Rather, the ability to take a [Bonus Attack] is a common type of benefit that you can get various ways, so the rules for it are located in one place, most importantly the bit about not getting to benefit from more than one in a given round.

Comment: I can be soo blind some times! It's specified every time it's used and in the standard action description too, just not in the definition. I'll wait a bit before accepting even if I don't think there is much else to say.